# A generic error in GDI+ when clearing

Tags: c#, api, gdi+

I got this exception when calling my project from API.

The method where the throw message is called from an event when we change some value, it will repaint the background and redraw string. This is never happen when using the application normally, but when i changed the value from the API, sometimes, it throw this.

---

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(Color color) at MyCompany.Project.GUI.Drawable.DrawLabel() in D:\Source\MyCompany\Project\GUI\Drawable.cs:line 191
   at MyCompany.Project.GUI.Drawable.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) in D:\Source\MyCompany\Project\GUI\Drawable.cs:line 26
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

---

Here is how my code looks like

```
public class Drawable : UserControl
{
    private Graphics g;
    public void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        DrawLabel();
    }
    private void DrawLabel()
    {
        if ((TopLabels != null) || (LeftLabels != null))
        {    
            g.Clear( BackColor ); //tje error is in here.
            g = CreateGraphics();
            /* another things to do*/
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the Graphics from OnPaint() to your DrawLabel() method.

Change:

```
DrawLabel();
```

To:

```
DrawLabel(e.Graphics);
```

And change:

```
private void DrawLabel()
```

To:

```
private void DrawLabel(Graphics g)
```

...and get rid of the CreateGraphics() call.

Comment: Why should I get rid the create graphics ? I mean, the draw label is called not only from onPaint, but the one who calls error is the on paint mehod. Can you give me an explaination ?

Comment: Because CreateGraphics() returns a **temporary** surface that gets erased when the control refreshes.  It's almost never the correct way to do it...